# Scrollable content to bottom of screen

Tags: css

I have this layout I am trying to achieve. Basically similar to what facebook have for messages (`facebook.com/messages`)

I have been trying it out here but with partial luck:
https://jsfiddle.net/3nd0b17m/23/
[image]

Basically the screen section scroll bar should end at the end of the screen and now further down.
Could anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would go about this, is make the sidebar position fixed, to make sure it stays nicely in place while you scroll the rest of the page.

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odukje08/3/

Good luck!

Edit: I added some flex properties to the sidebar, to make it more responsive and always have the right height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.left-bottom {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
}
.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-top">
    <p>
    This is the top
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="left-bottom">
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
      <p>
      stuff
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <h1>
  hello
  </h1>
  <p>
  this is the right side. You can scroll me too!
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The left side is the main issue. The bottom of the scrollbar is still beneath the window

Comment: @strangeQuirks I have fixed that problem by adding some flex properties :)